# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: react-native, graphql

````
When i try to integrate with mutation using apollo i got this error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead react native

src/Mutation


```
export const SIGNIN_USER = gql `
mutation signinUser($usersignin:UserSigninInput!) {
  user:signinUser(userSignin:$usersignin) {
    token
  }
} 
`
```
src/Login.js
const Login = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });
  const [signinUser,{error,loading,data}] = useMutation(SIGNIN_USER)  

  if (loading) return <Text>Loading... </Text>
  if (error) return <Text>{error}</Text>

  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("values are ==>",values)
    signinUser({
            variables: {
              userSignin: values
            }
          })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.titleView} >
            <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ height: hp('5%') }}></View>    
            <TextInput placeholder='Please Enter Email' style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('email', text)}
              value={values.firstName} />  
            <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Please Enter Password' style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('password', text)} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonView} onPress={handleSubmit} >
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Signin</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
  )
}
````

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead What is wrong in my code ?Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Error]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Comment: Posting code with an error message is unhelpful and unlikely to get a response. Folks need context.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value should be `value={values.email}` like this:

```
<TextInput 
  placeholder='Please Enter 
  Email' style={styles.textInput} 
  onChangeText={(text) => 
  handleChange('email', text)}
  value={values.email}
/>
```

Comment: yes , i forgot it, i edited and after run i got this  [Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400] what is wrong ?

Comment: I run this query in playground it's work properly, But when i used this in fronted i got this error?